# Sending HTML Email results in Email displaying HTML source (Codeigniter Email Class)

Tags: php, mysql, email, codeigniter

I am having problems with email sent via the email class in Codeigniter displaying the source HTML code in the email message instead of the rendered HTML view. For testing, I am currently having CI on XAMPP on Windows, and using Gmail SMTP to send to the same gmail address.

The function that sends the email is as follows:

```
$config = Array(
        'protocol' => 'smtp',
        'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
        'smtp_port' => 465,
        'smtp_user' => 'myaccountname@gmail.com',
        'smtp_pass' => 'mygmailpassword',
        );

    $this->load->library('email', $config); 
    $this->email->from($this->config->item('webmaster_email', 'tank_auth'), $this->config->item('website_name', 'tank_auth'));
    $this->email->reply_to($this->config->item('webmaster_email', 'tank_auth'), $this->config->item('website_name', 'tank_auth'));
    $this->email->to($email);
    $this->email->subject(sprintf($this->lang->line('auth_subject_'.$type), $this->config->item('website_name', 'tank_auth')));
    $this->email->message($this->load->view('email/'.$type.'-html', $data, TRUE));
    $this->email->set_alt_message($this->load->view('email/'.$type.'-txt', $data, TRUE));

    $this->email->set_newline("\r\n"); // require this, otherwise sending via gmail times out

    $this->email->send();
```

There is no problem getting the text version sent. The view loaded is a html file that will be emailed out.

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head><title>Welcome to <?php echo $site_name; ?>!</title></head>
<body>
<div style="max-width: 800px; margin: 0; padding: 30px 0;">
<table width="80%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<td width="5%"></td>
<td align="left" width="95%" style="font: 13px/18px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">
<h2 style="font: normal 20px/23px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; margin: 0; padding: 0 0 18px; color: black;">Welcome to <?php echo $site_name; ?>!</h2>
Thanks for joining <?php echo $site_name; ?>. We listed your sign in details below, make sure you keep them safe.<br />
To verify your email address, please follow this link:<br />
<br />
<big style="font: 16px/18px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;"><b><a href="<?php echo site_url('/auth/activate/'.$user_id.'/'.$new_email_key); ?>" style="color: #3366cc;">Finish your registration...</a></b></big><br />
<br />
Link doesn't work? Copy the following link to your browser address bar:<br />
<nobr><a href="<?php echo site_url('/auth/activate/'.$user_id.'/'.$new_email_key); ?>" style="color: #3366cc;"><?php echo site_url('/auth/activate/'.$user_id.'/'.$new_email_key); ?></a></nobr><br />
<br />
Please verify your email within <?php echo $activation_period; ?> hours, otherwise your registration will become invalid and you will have to register again.<br />
<br />
<br />
<?php if (strlen($username) > 0) { ?>Your username: <?php echo $username; ?><br /><?php } ?>
Your email address: <?php echo $email; ?><br />
<?php if (isset($password)) { /* ?>Your password: <?php echo $password; ?><br /><?php */ } ?>
<br />
<br />
Have fun!<br />
The <?php echo $site_name; ?> Team
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Any ideas how to get HTML emails sent to be rendered instead of displaying its source code?

Comment: You can't have PHP in an email body. I am also not sure you need the <html> or <body> tags.

Comment: @Nik: The PHP is *generating* the HTML that is sent, it's not actually *in* the email body.

Comment: Isn't the second code segment the HTML in the email? There is PHP in there. Obviously the first code segment is the generation.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Try adding the `mailtype` to the config:

```
$config = Array(
    'mailtype' => 'html',
    ...etc...
);
```

See http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/email.html

Answer (score 20):

Try this

```
$this->email->set_mailtype("html");
```

Comment: thanks for this, really extrange. Need to set twice? or inside the $this->load->library('email', $config); the $config it's not working. thanks again

Answer (score 6):

> Add these two lines after loading your codeigniter mail library

```
$this->email->set_header('MIME-Version', '1.0; charset=utf-8');
$this->email->set_header('Content-type', 'text/html');
```

full configuration: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38740292/4376484

Comment: Call to undefined method CI_Email::set_header()

Answer (score 3):

Append the line commented in the example below:

```
$config['protocol'] = 'sendmail';
$config['mailpath'] = '/usr/sbin/sendmail';
$config['charset'] = 'iso-8859-1';
$config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;
$config['mailtype'] = 'html'; // Append This Line
$this->email->initialize($config);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Set $config['protocol'] = "sendmail";
```

has fixed that for me