# Email showing html source when i send email using codignator email class

Tags: codeigniter, email

I have a problem in sending html mail with attachment in codeignitor using codeignitor email class the mail showing html code instead of html view.

i had set the mailtype as html in config below is my code

```
$message="<p>test</p>";
$mail_to = "email@gmail.com";
$from_mail = $useremail;
$from_name = $userfname;
$reply_to = $useremail;
$subject = "Abstract Details";



$file_name = $datamail['varafile'];
$path = realpath('uploads/abstract');

// Read the file content
$file = $path.'/'.$file_name;

$config = array (
              'protocol' =>'sendmail',
                          'mailtype' => 'html',
                          'charset'  => 'utf-8',
                          'priority' => '1'
                               );
       $this->load->library('email',$config);


      $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");

       $this->email->from($from_mail,$from_name);
        $this->email->to($mail_to);    
        $this->email->subject($subject);      
        $this->email->message($message);
        $this->email->attach($file);
        if($this->email->send()){
        echo "Mail send successfully";

        }else{
         echo "Error in sending mail";

        }
```

Comment: Did @Adam Westbrook answer your question?  Because you should acknowledge it.  Or if you figured it out you should post your solution.  Just saying, that's how it works.

Answer (score 5):

> configure it like this way

```
$config = Array(
    'protocol' => 'sendmail',
    'mailtype' => 'html',
    'smtp_host' => '', //your SMTP host
    'smtp_port' => 26,
    'smtp_user' => '', //your SMTP email address
    'smtp_pass' => '', //your SMTP email password
    'charset' => 'iso-8859-1',
    'wordwrap' => TRUE
);
$this->load->library('email', $config);
$this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
$this->email->set_header('MIME-Version', '1.0; charset=utf-8'); //must add this line
$this->email->set_header('Content-type', 'text/html'); //must add this line

$this->email->from('', ''); //from/sender email [with name (optional)]
$this->email->to(); //to/receiver email

$this->email->subject(''); //email subject
$message = $this->load->view('...directory.../...filename...',$data,TRUE); //html template/body with dynamic data
$this->email->message($message);
$this->email->send();
```

Comment: $this->email->set_header('MIME-Version', '1.0; charset=utf-8');
$this->email->set_header('Content-type', 'text/html'); 
above 2 lines worked for me :)

Answer (score 0):

[Apologies to all, I don't have enough rep to comment for clarification]

I just tried your exact code (minus the attachment bits) and all worked fine sending HTML email to a Gmail account, I'll provide my full working class below:

```
class rohithipix extends CI_Controller {

    public function html_email() {

        $message = "<h1>start</h1><p>test</p>";
        $mail_to = "test@gmail.com";
        $from_mail = 'test2@gmail.com';
        $from_name = 'dave';
        $reply_to = 'test2@gmail.com';
        $subject = "Abstract Details";

        //$file_name = $datamail['varafile'];
        //$path = realpath('uploads/abstract');

        // Read the file content
        //$file = $path . '/' . $file_name;

        $config = array(
            'protocol' => 'sendmail',
            'mailtype' => 'html',
            'charset' => 'utf-8',
            'priority' => '1'
        );
        $this->load->library('email', $config);


        $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");

        $this->email->from($from_mail, $from_name);
        $this->email->to($mail_to);
        $this->email->subject($subject);
        $this->email->message($message);
        //$this->email->attach($file);
        if ($this->email->send()) {
            echo "Mail send successfully";
        } else {
            echo "Error in sending mail";
        }
    }

}
```

What email client are you attempting to send these to while testing?