# Codeigniter - Email Class - HTML email load view

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, email

I need to send an HTML email but in the message I add to load a HTML file from the view, but when I send email and receive it, but email is blank no text getting from the view file please suggest.

```
public function sendUserMail($mail) {
            $data=true;
            $lang = $this->input->post("lang");
            $this->email->from('noreply@giftotravel.pk', 'Halalat');
            $this->email->to($mail); 
            $this->email->subject('Halalat Newsletter Subscription');
            $this->email->set_mailtype("html");
             if ($lang == "en") {
            $this->email->message = $this->load->view('email', $data, TRUE);
            }
            else  
            {
            $this->email->message('<img src="http://fahad.myradio.pk/assests/images/ar/bg_ar3.jpg" />');   
            }
            //$this->email->attach('/home/content/f/a/h/fahadghafoor/html/fahad/assests/images/en/bg_en2.jpg');//attachement testing done
            $this->email->send();
            echo $this->email->print_debugger();
        }
```

Comment: show your view file code

Comment: `<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en-US">
  <body>
  <h1> Testing HTML EMAIL </h1>

  </body>
</html> `

Comment: Codeigniter full HTML mail configuration: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38740292/4376484

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting the email message should be like this:

```
$this->email->message($this->load->view('email', $data, TRUE));
```

Comment: Done, you correct my mistake i just wait for 5 minutes then i accept your answer thankyou so much.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$msg = $this->load->view('email', $data , true);
$this->email->message($msg);
```

Comment: Teacher, i already done with the below code provided by Arnelle but i saved this pattern also thanks for your guide and time.

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21727259/wordpress-display-post-from-categories) Please Suggest

Comment: Sorry but I dont work on Wordpress , so cannot suggest you anything on that. :)

Comment: Np Teacher I Will Search On This Topic More N More!