# Wordpress - Display Post from categories

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to display a limited post from a specific category but with a page title , little description of page and also a read more link mention it, whats the procedure to i get this or guide me some details about the wordpress coding because i am very new in it.

I dont need to paste code in page.php i need to display this only on one specific page.

Basically i want to make a custom news column on page and i need to get post from category news but limit of five and when the new post added in category automatic display on home page i try lots of plugins but i still didn't get the exact solution all the time differs that's why i need to make a proper and permanent coding.

Comment: what you have tried yet?

Comment: i tried to get 5 post with title, short description and read more link display on home page.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a custom page template and then adding `wp_query` on it should work. After creating the template, you can create a page then set the template to the new custom page template you created. For example: create a News Page Template. In your theme, create news-template.php then add this code:

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: News Page Template
 *
 */

// add your markup here and wp_query

?>
```