# Formatting HTML in codeigniter emails

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, email

I have to send an email to the user but the email must be HTML formatted. I've read other posts here but that didnt help.

Here's my code from controller:

```
public function reply_post(){

    $to = $this->input->post('contact_email');
    $subject = $this->input->post('contact_subject');
    $header_message = "<html><head><title>".$subject."</title></head><body>";
    $footer_message = "</body></html>";
    $input_msg = $this->input->post('contact_reply');
    $msg = $header_message.$input_msg.$footer_message;
    $from = "admin@XXXXXXX.com";

    $config = Array(
      'protocol' => 'smtp',
      'smtp_host' => 'mail.XXXXXX.com',
      'smtp_port' => XXX,
      'smtp_user' => 'admin@XXXXX.com', // change it to yours
      'smtp_pass' => 'XXXXX', // change it to yours
      'mailtype' => 'html',
      'charset' => 'iso-8859-1',
      'wordwrap' => TRUE
    );

    $this->load->library('email', $config);
    $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
    $this->email->from($from, "Admin"); // change it to yours
    $this->email->to($to);// change it to yours
    $this->email->subject($subject);
    $this->email->message($msg);

    if($this->email->send()){
      $msg = 'Email sent.';
    } else {
        log_message('error','Email did not send');
        $msg = "Email Did not send";
    }
    $this->finish($msg);
}
```

The message that i get from the form is via Summernote WYSIWYG editor so it is already HTML formatted. However, when i receive the email, It doesnt apply HTML tags to it and all of the tags are visible. Its like somehow the mailtype is set to 'text', even after setting it to HTML in the config.

Comment: try adding `$this->email->set_mailtype("html");`

Comment: isnt that already added in the config array `mailtype => html`

Comment: It did work @AnmolRaghuvanshi. Dont mind but do you have an explanation for this? because it was already present in the config file

Comment: I was using summernote, so HTML output wasnt rendered. I've tried the same code in Bootstrap WYSIWYG editor and that worked fine there.

Comment: post the explanation as an answer to this question

Comment: Codeigniter full HTML mail configuration: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38740292/4376484

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting config options doesn't work unless you initialize them. Add this after your $config array:

```
$this->email->initialize($config);
```

So you didn't intealize  it So it didn't work further adding

```
 adding $this->email->set_mailtype("html");
```

may solve your problem.

**Load library then initialize**

Comment: How come it worked when i sent the data using bootstrap wysiwyg editor. But this didnt work in summernote?

Comment: And config was already passed to the library loading function. It initialized everything, except the mailtype?

Comment: @cyberrspiritt  btw i am not aware of bootstrap wysiwyg and summernote

Comment: Preferences are set by passing an array of preference values to the email initialize function. see doc `setting email preferences` https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/email.html

Comment: Ohk... Thanx for the help.